# Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/ProgramData/hashicorp/vagrant-vmware-desktop/certificates/vagrant-utility.client.crt

Tags: windows, vagrant

In my windows 10, after I installed

```
​vagrant plugin install vagrant-vmware-desktop
```

then i execute `vagrant up` I get error:1

```
>vagrant up
Vagrant encountered an error while attempting to load the utility
service key file. This error can occur if the Vagrant VMware Utility
has not yet been installed, or if it was installed incorrectly. If
this error persists after running the Vagrant VMware Utility installer
again, please contact support at: support@hashicorp.com

Information about the Vagrant VMware Utility, including installation
instruction, can be found here:

  https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vmware/vagrant-vmware-utility.html

  Path:  C:/ProgramData/hashicorp/vagrant-vmware-desktop/certificates/vagrant-utility.client.crt
  Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/ProgramData/hashicorp/vagrant-vmware-desktop/certificates/vagrant-utility.client.crt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the Vagrant Vmware utility is missing, you can run the following command and check if the Vmware utility service is running or not

```
net start vagrant-vmware-utility
```

If it is not present, install it from [here](https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant-vmware-utility/1.0.21/vagrant-vmware-utility_1.0.21_x86_64.msi) for windows. you can look for other links for different platforms.

Once installed re-install the utility -

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vmware-desktop
```

After installation is complete you should have a folder similar to this:

```
C:\HashiCorp\VagrantVMwareUtility
```